# Kubernetes: Prometheus annotations and endpoint name

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

can someone answer me the following questions, otherwise it's a little unclear to me.

1. How do I understand and where to look what annotations exist at all? Is there a list somewhere or template?
2. Standard annotations work and prometheus sees this service. Everything is ok with this.

   annotations:
   prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
   prometheus.io/path: '/actuator/prometheus'
   prometheus.io/port: '8700'
3. But the service is displayed as Endpoint IP. Is there any possibility, setting, so that not Endpoint IP is displayed in prometheus targets, but the service name and namespace?

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about your setup ? Are you using the prometheus operator ? A chart Helm ? A custom install ?

Comment: @MarcABOUCHACRA - Helm. https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/prometheus-community/prometheus

Answer (score 1):

I'll try and give you some answer based on what I understand from your question.

1. About the annotations : to know wich are the one used by the Helm chart, well there is no magic here, you need to read the templates files. Although, most of those annotations are listed in the `values.yaml` file under the `relabel_configs` section. You'll find blocks like this one

```yaml
        relabel_configs:
          - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
            action: keep
            regex: true
```

This means that all the ressource of this job that has the `prometheus.io/scrape` annotation with the value `true` will be scrapped.

2. Yes, this is normal based on the content of the `values.yaml` file.
3. On the target page, Prometheus will always print the IP address under the *Endpoint* column. However you can play with the configuration in order to print the namespace and ressource name under the *Labels* column if it's not already here.